# how do i receive a vector with the colnames after doing a specific sort in a dataframe

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have the following code, and i want the colnames of the sorted sequence v

```
             r<-6
    c<-6
    a<-LETTERS[rep(1:3,each=2)]
    b<-paste0(a,1:2)
    set.seed(1)
    M<-matrix(rnorm(1:36),r,c)
    M<-t(M)
    colnames(M)<-t(b)
    dF<-data.frame(M)
    seq1<-seq(1,length(dF),2)
    f<-c()
    names<-c()
    for (i in seq1) {
      f[i]<-dF[1,i]
      v<-sort(f)
    }
print(dF)
          A1          A2         B1          B2          C1         C2
1 -0.6264538  0.18364332 -0.8356286  1.59528080  0.32950777 -0.8204684
2  0.4874291  0.73832471  0.5757814 -0.30538839  1.51178117  0.3898432
3 -0.6212406 -2.21469989  1.1249309 -0.04493361 -0.01619026  0.9438362
4  0.8212212  0.59390132  0.9189774  0.78213630  0.07456498 -1.9893517
5  0.6198257 -0.05612874 -0.1557955 -1.47075238 -0.47815006  0.4179416
6  1.3586796 -0.10278773  0.3876716 -0.05380504 -1.37705956 -0.4149946
print(v)
-0.8356286 -0.6264538  0.3295078
```

When v is sorted depending on the size of the numbers i would like to receive a vector with the colnames of the list of v in the same order. So i would like to receive this vector in this case. c("B1","A1","C1")
This is just a reduced data frame and duplicates may exist.

What should i add to my code? Thank you in advanced

Comment: When using random sample data you should always use a fixed random seed (see `?set.seed`); otherwise it will be impossible to reproduce your sample data and expected output.

Comment: I have updated to a fixed random seed

Comment: *"v is sorted depending on the size of the numbers"* I don't understand what that means or what you're trying to do. What is `v`? Do you want to sort `dF`? If so, how? PS. Without reporting the fixed random seed, we still can't reproduce your data.

Comment: What I meant by "using a fixed random seed" is to use something like `set.seed(1234)`  *before* calling `rnorm(36)`.

Comment: I want to sort the first row. Which i have done, but i also want to receive the colnames of the sorted vector. If i run .Random.seed it allways prints the same values soit should be fixed now.

Comment: Sorry but no, it's not fixed. Your code is not reproducible (and actually throws an error). Did you actually try this yourself? I still don't understand what `v` is. And what does `v` have to do with `dF`?

Comment: i made a misprint it should be able to be reproduced now, i have tested it.  Here         for (i in seq1) {
              f[i]<-dF[1,i]
              v<-sort(f)                                                                                                         i sort every second column in the first row and name the sorted vector v. What i want is to receive a vector with the matching column names of the sorted vector v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
apply(dF[seq(1, ncol(dF), by = 2)], 1, function(x)
    names(dF[seq(1, ncol(dF), by = 2)])[order(x)])[, 1]
#[1] "B1" "A1" "C1"
```

Or to get a `matrix` of column names for all 6 rows.

```
t(apply(dF[seq(1, ncol(dF), by = 2)], 1, function(x)
    names(dF[seq(1, ncol(dF), by = 2)])[order(x)]))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "B1" "A1" "C1"
#[2,] "A1" "B1" "C1"
#[3,] "A1" "C1" "B1"
#[4,] "C1" "A1" "B1"
#[5,] "C1" "B1" "A1"
#[6,] "C1" "B1" "A1"
```

Explanation: `dF[seq(1, ncol(dF), by = 2)]` selects columns 1, 3, 5, ..., and `apply(..., 1, function(x) names(dF[seq(1, ncol(dF), by = 2)])[order(x)])` returns the column names of the ordered entries by row.

Comment: It is close. The output should be "B1" "A1" "C1" instead of "B1" "A1" "A2". Since "A2" is not in the 1st 3rd or 5th column

Comment: @ChristianSkjøth I see; I wasn't sure whether you wanted columns 1, 3, 5,... or columns 2, 4, 6, ...; there was also a mistake in my code which I fixed. Please take a look. This reproduces your expected output.

Comment: You're very welcome @ChristianSkjøth; please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you help future SO readers who are searching for answers and keep SO tidy.